# Scope variable error: Cannot read property ... of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in my code i have a table and i want to fill a form with the row i clicked.
The table:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>project</th>
    <th>start</th>
    <th>end</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="booking in myBookingsList" ng-click="bookingClicked(booking)">
    <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
    <td>{{booking.usersProjects.project.name}}</td>
    <td>{{booking.start | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' }}</td>
    <td>{{booking.end | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' }}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

here is the function for ng-click:

```
$scope.bookingClicked = function(booking){
    $scope.newBooking = {};
    $scope.newBooking.project = booking.usersProjects.project.name;
    $scope.newBooking.id = booking.id;
    $scope.newBooking.startDate = $filter('date')(booking.start, "yyyy-MM-dd");
    $scope.newBooking.startTime = new Date(booking.start);
    $scope.newBooking.endDate = $filter('date')(booking.end, "yyyy-MM-dd");
    $scope.newBooking.endTime = new Date(booking.end);
};
```

The problem is the 2nd line where i get

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'project' of undefined
```

So what is the problem here? Another part of the app takes the data from from and submits it. This is working fine and there i have

```
$scope.newBooking = {};
//timepicker values must be initialized
$scope.newBooking.startTime = new Date();
$scope.newBooking.endTime = new Date();
```

Here is an example for booking object that is fed to function:

```
{
    "id": 50,
    "self": "http://localhost:8080/timetracker-backend/timetracker/booking/50",
    "start": 1434103331000,
    "end": 1434110531000,
    "usersProjects": {
        "id": 43,
        "self": "http://localhost:8080/timetracker-backend/timetracker/usersprojects/43",
        "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "self": "http://localhost:8080/timetracker-backend/timetracker/user/1",
            "name": "timetrackerAdmin",
            "role": "ADMIN"
        },
        "project": {
            "id": 42,
            "self": "http://localhost:8080/timetracker-backend/timetracker/project/42",
            "name": "project four",
            "description": "description p4"
        }
    }
}
```

This looks similar to me??

Comment: what are the contents of `myBookingsList`? It seems that the `usersProjects` property is undefined for the booking you are clicking

Comment: no i debugged into this line and the right side yields the correct value! added example object

Comment: You could try passing just the booking ID back to the controller and then fetching it from your data store

Comment: thats bad - the complete object is there - as described above. and the problem is not the data but the scope variable. Why $scope.newBooking.project is not working??

Comment: I know, it's not the best for performance. Sorry, can't help you any further :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $scope.newBooking = {};

there is no object name **project** so it is showing console error, you create an empty object in your answer as

```
 $scope.newBooking.project = {};
```

it means

```
$scope.newBooking= {
project : {} 
}
```

you line works as above code, now $scope.newBooking has or know above **project object**  so, it works fine

Comment: Your question was not clear. you need to fill the form or json array

Comment: the "booking" fed to function comes from "booking in myBookingsList". I want to fill an empty form with one item from list - the one clicked. the left side are the empty form the right side are the values to be filled into the form. but as i said in my answer if i add $scope.newBooking.project = {}; all is working fine - but why?

Comment: In $scope.newBooking = {}; there is no object name project so it is showing that error, you create an empty object $scope.newBooking.project = {}; it means $scope.newBooking= {project : {} } you line works as this, now $scope.newBooking has project = {} in it so, it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Accidentally i found a solution. It is working if i add `$scope.newBooking.project = {};`

so the function is now

```
$scope.bookingClicked = function(booking){
    $scope.newBooking = {};
    $scope.newBooking.project = {};
    $scope.newBooking.project = booking.usersProjects.project.name;
    $scope.newBooking.id = booking.id;
    $scope.newBooking.startDate = $filter('date')(booking.start, "yyyy-MM-dd");
    $scope.newBooking.startTime = new Date(booking.start);
    $scope.newBooking.endDate = $filter('date')(booking.end, "yyyy-MM-dd");
    $scope.newBooking.endTime = new Date(booking.end);
};
```

But whoever can me tell why this is only working with this additional line will get accepted.

Comment: that makes no sense... :)

Comment: the additional problem is: i am absolute angularjs/js beginner. But now it is working fine.

Comment: The problem was either because you didn't have this line `$scope.newBooking = {};` or because  `booking.usersProjects` was undefined when you were trying to call `$scope.newBooking.project = booking.usersProjects.project.name;`